# Remove Joomla Activation Email for confirming user email... LOCALHOST

Tags: email, joomla, registration, activation

i want to stop this functionality of Activation Email. when i tried to register an account locally, it shows activation error. i want to remove these functionality. how can i do that ?

thanks in advance.

Notice: Could not instantiate mail function.

error : " Registration failed: An error was encountered while sending the registration email. A message has been sent to the administrator of this site ".

bellow answer works as it stops activation email and register user with activated account... but still shows this notice... what should i do ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Joomla backend, go to:

**Users** *(top menu)* >> **User Manager** >> **Options**

and there is a parameter called **New User Account Activation**. Set this to **none**

Hoipe this helps

Comment: Are you sure you set the option to **none** cause this error occurs when it is set to **self** or **admin**. There are a few localhosts such as Wampserver which don't support the mail function